# Почему в записях в PostgreSQL неверное время и как это исправить?

Tags: postgresql

```
$ date
Thu Nov 17 17:53:26 MSK 2016
```

Это верно, то есть на стороне OS все в порядке. Тогда дело конкретно в PostgreSQL.

Время в записях таблиц отстает на 3 часа. Как это исправить?

Comment: Полагаю, у Вас в БД даты записаны в зоне UTC, это даже более правильный подход. Просто при получении даты подставляйте нужную timezone.

Comment: @spopovru спасибо, вы правы. Так даже лучше, просто в настройках проекта указал Time Zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В PostgreeSQL типы `time` и `timestamp` могут быть объявлены как учитывающие часовой пояс

```
timestamp with time zone
```

так и не учитывающие

```
timestamp without time zone
```

или просто

```
timestamp
```

Если поле объявлено как учитывающее часовой пояс, то при записи данных в таблицу время записывается в UTC на основании текущего часового пояса пользователя, а выдается в виде локального времени, опять таки, на основании текущего часового пояса пользователя.

Если же часовой пояс не учитывается, то никакие манипуляции с временем не производятся. Что записали, то и прочитали.

Текущий часовой пояс пользователя можно изменить, установив параметр TIMEZONE для сеанса пользователя

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Решил ситуацию указанием Time Zone в настройках проекта, а в БД ничего не трогал.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в моем случае БД использовалась в RoR проекте и, как подсказал @spopovru, достаточно было в конфигурации RoR указать Time Zone. После этого на сайте время выводилось как надо.

Этот подход еще хорош тем, что можно дать пользователям менять часовую зону (город) на свою, тогда на сайте будет отображаться время для пользователя.